# Elasticsearch best practice (addresses)

Tags: elasticsearch

we are going to hold a mass of address data (mass in eyes of my company - about 150.000 to 500.000 rows per Customer).

The address data contains about 5 columns:

1. Name1
2. Name2
3. Street (+ No)
4. Postcode
5. City

Maybe later some more stuff (like phone, mail etc.)

Is it the best way to assign a pool of addresses per customer to one shard? (A user of the application is assigned to a customer and shares the address pool to all users of customer)

Answer (score 0):

"Jargon wise" give each Customer their own index (with the same mapping). Elasticsearch can query multiple indices with a single query. An index may consist of many shards. For 150 - 500.000 documents, you don't need [that many shards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/kagillion-shards.html). You might be fine with just one, but depending on the amount of queries made, at least check between 1 - 5.